# Installing AMD Catalyst 13.12 64 bit

Tags: drivers, ati, 64-bit, radeon, fglrx

I have an AMD E1-1200 processor on my computer. After trying to install the current AMD Catalyst (13.12) drivers, my computer's display wouldn't work and I would boot into command prompt.

I of course had to uninstall the drivers, and I managed to get back up and running. This is apparently, a common issue with Catalyst 13.12.

If you want to see my error log you can find it [HERE](http://pastebin.com/xQdm579K).

I went on here to look for tutorials of how to install Catalyst 13.12 (64 bit) on Ubuntu and couldn't find any solution that I could understand (I'm a noob) to my problem. Can anyone give me some advice to installing Catalyst 13.12 properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I found that people are having the same runing the kelner version 3.11. You need to use kernel below 3.11 and it will work. Hopefully they will fix this issue soon

Here is the link that you can look up :)
http://www.rurapenthe.me/2014/02/installing-amd-catalyst-1312-on-ubuntu.html